# bcmath extention is enabled in my ubuntu system for php 8.2, but drupal 10 commerce module it is showing error

Tags: php, docker, drupal, bcmath

```
$ php -i | grep -i bcmath
PHP Warning:  Module "gd" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
bcmath
BCMath support => enabled
bcmath.scale => 1 => 1
```

my docker compose file setup:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
  drupal:
    image: drupal:10
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./web:/var/www/html
      - ./vendor:/opt/drupal/vendor
      - ./composer.json:/opt/drupal/composer.json
      - ./composer.lock:/opt/drupal/composer.lock
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USERNAME=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    restart: always

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. How is this problem related to Drupal or [tag:commerce]?

Comment: @NicoHaase I believe the question is within the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using drupal:10 image

Created a linked Dockerfile with php image mapped to the working directory & i had to add this code to install the bcmath extension inside the container:

**`RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath`**

now its working !

Comment: Congrats, but could you share a bit more? How did you do this? In which file did you place that line? How did you verify it is working? Please edit the answer by adding more context to complete it.

Comment: Added some more details to my answer, thanks for the insight.

Comment: If it answers your question, please give it the green checkmark as well to mark the question as solved.